# Symfony2 routing with two bundles issue

Tags: php, symfony, routes, bundle

I have issue with routing in my Symfony 2 application.

This application contains 2 bundles MainSiteBundle and GalleryBundle
I configured routing with prefixes like that:

app/config/routing.yml

```
honorata_photo_main_site:
resource: "@HonorataPhotoMainSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /

honorata_photo_gallery:
resource: "@HonorataPhotoGalleryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /gallery
```

Routine inside each bundle is not important now because i have issue with this.

When I try to access / route everything works fine (even with sub routes inside bundle)
When I try to access /gallery route it shows me error like:

```
No route found for "GET ery"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

Why Symfony 2 router cuts first 3 letters after /     ?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that inside `"@HonorataPhotoMainSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"` you have some more general route defined.

Try reversing the order of definition:

```
honorata_photo_gallery:
    resource: "@HonorataPhotoGalleryBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /gallery

honorata_photo_main_site:
    resource: "@HonorataPhotoMainSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Comment: I tried. Same error. Yes I have defined some more specific routes inside these routings. Still cuts 3 first letters form route.. I have no idea why

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `MainSite` routing file and then loading `/gallery`? The strange part is that it does not cut first 3 chars but 4 ("gall"). You don't by any silly chance have defined `/gall` route in `MainBundle`? :)

Answer (score 0):

Subject resolved and closed !

Problem was that /gallery path already exist in MainSiteBundle I realised that using php app/console route:debug and after deeper analysis :)

Next time I will make routing log to prevent that in the future.